# How can I set a command in variable and then use it for remote operation

Tags: powershell, variables, remoting

Hey guys I am currently trying to create a script that Start/Stops Services remotely. However I want also to set the *Start/Stop-Service* command in a variable that will be asking the user weather he wants to start or stop the service.

I am now remoting the *Start/Stop service* via these commands.

```
Stop-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -ComputerName $Machine -Name $Service) 
Start-Service -InputObject $(Get-Service -ComputerName $Machine -Name $Service)
```

I want to set a variable that will ask the user weather he wants to start or stop it:

```
$Operation = Read-Host "Start-Service or Stop-Service?" | Out-String
```

I came up with this idea but this does not work.

```
$Operation -InputObject $(Get-Service -ComputerName $Machine -Name $Service)
```

Please advise how can this be accomplished.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic version of what you want to achieve. You can do lot more with validations.

```
$Operation = Read-Host "Start-Service or Stop-Service?"
$servicename= Read-host "Enter the service name: "
$machine = Read-host "Enter the ComputerName: "
if($Operation -eq "Start-Service")
{
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Machine -Name $Service | Start-Service
}
Else
{
    Get-Service -ComputerName $Machine -Name $Service | Stop-Service -Force 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Ranadip, thanks for your fast answer, this solution works fine for me.

Comment: np. Enjoy coding